# Associating parcel label to points attribute table using QGIS

Tags: qgis, wfs, parcel

I'm pretty much a beginner in QGIS.

What I need is to associate each feature of a layer(bunch of points basically, each with it's own unique numbered value) to the parcel label inside which it is located.

I suppose I need to use "Join attributes by location" from "Data Management Tools", but it's not really working for me so far.
Btw the parcels information is from a WFS source.

Does the data from WFS need to be downloaded first and exported into a shapefile or something else?

[image: image host]

Comment: Confused by the question, do you have one WFS and with one or more featuretypes, or data from multiple sources, that need to be spatially joined, one of which is a WFS.

Comment: Hi, yes one WFS with one featuretype, but I got it to work, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved my points feature and the area downloaded from WFS as ESRi shapefiles, then it worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).